# What is the best option to easily fix fragmented heap indexes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, performance

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 and also SQL Server 2012 SP2 on these servers.

I have a database in which there is a lot of heap indexes which are more than 90% fragmented.

What is the best option to easily fix these heap indexes?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to 'fix'? Fragmentation on its own means nothing.  Did you do aperf analysis that shows fragmentation to be an issue?

Comment: The best way to fix heap fragmentation is by creating a Clustered index

Answer (score 7):

Making the assumption that you are using SQL Server (because the RDBMS is going to matter here) you can do the following

```
ALTER TABLE tablename REBUILD
```

That being said you can read [this article by Paul Randal](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2930-fixing-heap-fragmentation/) as to why you shouldn't.  Unless you are using your table as a staging table where you want a quick import but then clean the table out later anyway you probably want to put a clustered index on your table.  At this point it won't be a heap and you have more options for dealing with fragmentation.

You generally want your CI to be small, unchanging and ever increasing (and unique is nice but not necessary).  The unchanging and ever increasing will minimize any fragmentation for the future.

Comment: article is dead